# Is there a way to get the plugin output of icinga2 on the commandline?

Tags: command-line-interface, icinga2

With icinga2 one can use `icingacli monitoring list` to get the monitoring results on the commandline.

I'm looking for the detailed output of the plugins/services (shown in icinga2 as 'plugin output', in icinga1 as 'status information').

Comment: is your question resolved, or is there anything left/unclear with the provided answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer the question with an example:

```
icingacli monitoring list services --host=myHostName --service=myServiceName --columns "host,service,service_output" --format='$host$: $service$ ($service_output$)'
```

To get just the plugin-output (so, **exactly what was asked for**) for all services on the machine "myHostName" ( the "--host" parameter can even be omitted):

```
icingacli monitoring list services \
    --host=myHostName  \
    --columns "service_output" \
    --format='$service_output$'
```

The icingacli help is very good. One can get information and examples with:

```
icingacli --help                            # basic help
icingacli monitoring list --help            # what information can you list
icingacli monitoring list services --help   # what information can you get from the services
```